# Why is my styled Component hover effect not working

Tags: reactjs, hover, styled-components

This is my first time using styledComponent.
Can someone tell me why my hover effect on SubmitBtn not working.
I just want to add hover effect on the submit button.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';



const SubmitBtn = styled.button`
        width: 50%;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
        borderRadius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: green;
        color: white;

        &:hover {
            background: darkgreen;
            color: grey;
        }
    `



<SubmitBtn>Submit Book</SubmitBtn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the SubmitBtn out of component, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return/render the component.

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const SubmitBtn = styled.button`
        width: 50%;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        margin: 8px 0;
        display: inline-block;
        border: none;
        borderRadius: 4px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: green;
        color: white;

        &:hover {
            background: darkgreen;
            color: grey;
        }
    `
export const App = () => <SubmitBtn>Submit Book</SubmitBtn>
```